# What is the encoding behind L"" in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode

I'm trying to find any information about the encoding behind `L""` strings?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160

I know `wchar_t` is undefined because it can be any multi-byte encoding. But what happens if I use an `L""` string? Even the docs just leave out the information.

```
auto s2 =  L"hello"; // const wchar_t* <-- it's undefined but why?
auto s3 =  u"hello"; // const char16_t*, encoded as UTF-16
auto s4 =  U"hello"; // const char32_t*, encoded as UTF-32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wchar_t` is a standard type, but its exact implementation is left to individual compilers.  Microsoft decided back when Unicode all fit into 16-bit quantities that `wchar_t` would be 2 bytes in size, and Windows would use UCS-2. Later, when Unicode exceeded 16-bit quantities, Windows was updated to use UTF-16, and since Windows operated on little-endian processors, that made it UTF-16LE.  `wchar_t` remained 2 bytes in size, which can handle UTF-16 values, using surrogate pairs for Unicode codepoints above U+FFFF.

Comment: @HelloWorld If he answered it, then mark it as answered.

Comment: Marked, but keep in mind, it takes a while that an answer is allowed to be accepted